# HTML UniCode Problem Characters are not displaying correctly in inputbox

Tags: html, utf-8

I am having a form and when i am trying to input text like some unicode characters and saving to database. While retrieving the data again the characters are replacing with '?' in **inputbox (input type="text")** characters. (**Note: the characters are correctly displaying in html body**)

I am having `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in mypage

My input is

```
Hợp đồng kinh tế
```

After retrieving the text is like

```
h?p d?ng kinh t?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the wrong question.

The problem is with Datatype in DATABASE only. I changed the datatype from **varchar** to **nvarchar**

Answer (score 0):

What database do you use? If it is MySQL, you may want to configure your connection accordingly:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/<your username>?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```